# make analog clock for blackberry 

Tags: blackberry

I want to make an Analog Clock In blackberry, and I want the hands of the clock to be custom images.

I gone through this thread [Help with analog clock code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Help-on-analog-clock-code/td-p/446201)  but didnt get it worked. Can any body help me to make an analog clock

**Update**
The code i am getting is from the supports forum

```
// How to use it

ClockBitmapField clock = new ClockBitmapField(face, Field.NON_FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER,
                                          hrPng, minPng, secPng);
```

**I can i use this to make an analog clock**

**How Can i use this**

```
 add(clock);

// Clock Face

class ClockBitmapField extends BitmapField {

Bitmap _face = null;
UpdateClockThread _updateClockThread = null;
Bitmap [] _hourBitmaps = null;
Bitmap [] _minBitmaps = null;
Bitmap [] _secBitmaps = null;

public ClockBitmapField(Bitmap face, long style, String [] hourPngs, String [] minPngs, String [] secPngs) {
    super(face, style);
    _face = face;
    _ourBitmap = new Bitmap(_face.getWidth(), _face.getHeight());
    this.setBitmap(_ourBitmap); // Swap to using work area
    _hourBitmaps = new Bitmap [hourPngs.length];
    for ( int i = 0; i < hourPngs.length; i++ ) {
        _hourBitmaps[i] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(hourPngs[i]);
    }
    _minBitmaps = new Bitmap [minPngs.length];
    for ( int i = 0; i < minPngs.length; i++ ) {
        _minBitmaps[i] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(minPngs[i]);
    }
    _secBitmaps = new Bitmap [secPngs.length];
    for ( int i = 0; i < secPngs.length; i++ ) {
        _secBitmaps[i] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(secPngs[i]);
    }
}
protected void onDisplay() {
    onExposed();
}
protected void onUnDisplay() {
    onObscured();
}
protected void onExposed() {
    if ( _updateClockThread == null || !_updateClockThread.isAlive() ) {
        _updateClockThread = new UpdateClockThread(_ourBitmap, _face, this, _hourBitmaps, _minBitmaps, _secBitmaps);
        _updateClockThread.start();
    }
}
protected void onObscured() {
    if ( _updateClockThread != null ) {
        _updateClockThread.stop();
        _updateClockThread = null;
    }
}
public void invalidate() {
    super.invalidate();
}
class UpdateClockThread extends Thread {
    private Calendar _cal = null;
    int _curHr = 0;
    int _curMin = 0;
    int _curSec = 0;
    Bitmap _face = null;
    int _faceWidth = 0;
    int _faceHeight = 0;
    _ourBitmap = null;
    Graphics _g = null;
    ClockBitmapField _ourField = null;
    long LONG_ONE_THOUSAND = 1000;
    boolean _stopped = false;
    Bitmap [] _hourBitmaps = null;
    Bitmap [] _minBitmaps = null;
    Bitmap [] _secBitmaps = null;
    public UpdateClockThread(Bitmap ourBitmap, Bitmap face, ClockBitmapField fieldToInvalidate, 
                             Bitmap [] hourBitmaps, Bitmap [] minBitmaps, Bitmap [] secBitmaps) {
        super();
        _cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        _face = face;
        _faceWidth = _face.getWidth();
        _faceHeight = _face.getHeight();
        _ourBitmap = ourBitmap;
        _g = new Graphics(_ourBitmap);
        _ourField = fieldToInvalidate;
    }
    public void run() {
        long timeToSleep = 0;
        while (!_stopped) {
            _g.setBackgroundColor(0x00191919);
            _g.clear();
            _g.drawBitmap(0, 0, _faceWidth, _faceHeight, _face, 0, 0);
            _cal.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            _curHr = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);                
            _curMin = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            _curHr = (_curHr * 5) + (5 * _curMin / 60);
            if (_curHr > 60) _curHr = _curHr - 60;
            _curSec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            _g.drawBitmap(0, 0, _faceWidth, _faceHeight, _secBitmaps[_curSec], 0, 0);
            _g.drawBitmap(0, 0, _faceWidth, _faceHeight, _minBitmaps[_curMin], 0, 0);
            _g.drawBitmap(0, 0, _faceWidth, _faceHeight, _hourBitmaps[_curHr], 0, 0);
            _ourField.invalidate();
            timeToSleep = LONG_ONE_THOUSAND - ( System.currentTimeMillis() % LONG_ONE_THOUSAND );
            if ( timeToSleep > 20 ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void stop() {
        _stopped = true;
    }
}

}
```

and make minutes as second
thanks and regards
[image: Face Image][image: Hour Image]  [image: Minuts Image]

Comment: That thread contains good code, did you try any of it? If so, then can you please specify what your problem is?

Comment: @medopal yes but i didnt know how to pass the bitmap in string[] so i cant use that code can you tell me how to do it

Comment: Update your question with the code, and point out which line of code you don't understand, then we might be able to help.

Comment: @medopal updated with the code... can you now see and give me the solution

Answer (score 3):

Just by looking at the code, it appears that the inputs: 
`String [] hourPngs, String [] minPngs, String [] secPngs` are each a list of filenames of images which represent the clock hands at each position.

In this snippet, he builds an array of 60 `Bitmaps` from the strings:

```
    _secBitmaps = new Bitmap [secPngs.length];
    for ( int i = 0; i < secPngs.length; i++ ) {
        _secBitmaps[i] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(secPngs[i]);
    }
```

Then, in this snippet you can see he gets the `Bitmap` object from a array by passing in the current "second" as the index:

```
_g.drawBitmap(0, 0, _faceWidth, _faceHeight, _secBitmaps[_curSec], 0, 0);
```

There doesn't appear to be any code where he rotates the images or anything.
So I guess that means you need 60 images for each clock hand. (180 images in total, plus the clock face).

Comment: i made the array of size 60 with having the file name of the images but not working ...

Comment: can you be more specific than "not working"? doesn't compile? throws exception? what appears on the screen?

Comment: i got null pointer exception .......... and when i press continue on simulator i can see only the face of the image which i have passed as a bitmap ..

Comment: sounds like one of your images didnt load.
if you wanna post a link to all your images I can try it (i dont wanna make the 180 images myself)

Comment: ok @icchanobot i am giving you the images... but i dont know how to put on link .....